# Не работает Custom Tag JSP

Tags: java, jsp, maven

Создал в maven web проект

```
src/
└── main
    ├── java
    │   └── com
    │       └── myapp
    │           └── web
    │               └── HelloTag.java
    └── webapp
        ├── index.jsp
        └── WEB-INF
            ├── custom.tld
            └── web.xml
```

Создал класс своего тега

```
package com.myapp.web;


import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

  public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
    out.println("Hello Custom Tag!");
  }
}
```

Описал тег

```
<taglib>
 <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
 <jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
 <short-name>My Custom Tag</short-name>
 <tag>
 <name>MyTag</name>
 <tag-class>com.myapp.web.HelloTag</tag-class>
 <body-content>empty</body-content>
 </tag>
</taglib>
```

Создал JSP страницу

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="WEB-INF/custom.tld"%>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>A sample custom tag</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ex:MyTag/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Собрал все это, залил на сервер, захожу по адресу в браузере в ответ ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл с зависимостями maven

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myapp.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.myapp.web.servlet</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>serv</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в вашем теге, а в подключаемой вами версии `JSP` и использовании `Tomcat 7`. [Метод](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory.html#getJspApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29) `getJspApplicationContext()` появился в `JSP 2.1`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Обратите внимание на использование `provided scope` - это необходимо поскольку `Tomcat` уже поставляется с нужными библиотеками и нет необходимости включать их в вашу сборку.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.

Comment: @fill не за что. Вы можете отметить ответ как верный, нажав галочку слева, чтобы закрыть вопрос